# Where are the SMTP settings in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I am looking at someone else's code and need to find the SMTP details. He is using CodeIgniter however, I can not figure out where the SMTP config is being set.

For example, he is sending mail like this:

```
function sendMail{
    $this->load->library('email');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->from($this->config->item('from_email'), $this->config->item('from_name'));
    $this->email->to(test@example.com);
    $this->email->subject('Subject is here');
    $message  = "Hello";
    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();

return true;
}
```

I can not see where the config files are set. He does have the `from_email` item and `from_name` item configured in a custom config file, but that file contains only these two lines.

The default config.php does not contain anything `smtp` related..

Any ideas where could I find it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for sending email with gmail smtp in codeigniter?

Comment: No, I don't know what SMTP the guy is using and I need to use the same in my code, so I have to figure out the settings for it.

Comment: $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@gmail.com'; //change this
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';

Comment: You can find it at php.ini and sendmail.ini. otherwise you have to set at CI

Answer (score 0):

From Codeigniter forum,

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
```

);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();

Check this [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20091027211607/http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/132443/)

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the config folder there might be a file called email.php into which default config items can be set. So they might be being set there.

These are called automatically when the email class is loaded, but can be overidden by setting them in the controller and initialising the class as described in the docs. 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html